# flutter release/production app view ios logs

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, logging

How can i view the logs for an app that runs in release mode (flutter run --release) on iOS (14.5) physical device? I tried logging with `print`, `debugPrint` nothing gets printed in the OS X console app (/System/Applications/Utilities/Console.app). i also tried in the terminal the 'flutter logs -v' command, nothing no logs or errors running this command.

Comment: A release mode build of an iOS app suppresses all console output from the app. You could have your app create its own log file in the documents directory and expose that file via the files app or a process in your app.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I was thinking of that but I find it more convenient to use an online service.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [sentry.io](https://sentry.io/welcome/), which lets you track errors and performance. They have an SDK for flutter and installing/implementing instructions to get started, once you setup a project.

Sentry is open-source and has paid options as well.

I don't know how you have built your backend, but if you use firebase you can use their [crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics) solution.

Comment: already using, very good tool but it's not designed for regular log collection, it's aimed at events collection (like crashlytics) , I asked them if I could do regular log collection and they said no.

Comment: Yeah that's true, but a trick that I use is to `FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.crash()` in the code logic, after you logged, it's definitely not optimal, and I look forward to a better solution, but I am very new to flutter and this is how I debug real device behavior...

Comment: good solution, will try it on ios now.